# How to test websocket action that contains countdown timer in django-channels?

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am using channels+DRF and one of restrictions in the project is countdown timer like if user is not responding in 15 seconds close his channel. How can I test that in async tests for consumers?